# How to scan huge tables in datastore

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

Here is my problem ..

We have a User table with over 50 million users. Now I want to retrieve some fbIds that I need to test a method (i.e. readUsersByFacebookIds())

My naive first attempt was to scan some records having a facebookId that is not null and then use those fbIds. This question timed out and my colleague mentioned that DataStore could have a hard time with NOT_EQUAL. I.e. can't use the index. (Sounds reasonable ...)

Attempt #1 Times out i.e. > 60 secs

```
public String testFbFriends(int count) {
    try {
        DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
        Query q = new Query("User");
        q.setFilter(new FilterPredicate("facebookId", Query.FilterOperator.NOT_EQUAL, null));
        PreparedQuery pq = ds.prepare(q);
        List<String> fbIds = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Entity userE : pq.asIterable(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(count).chunkSize(100))) {
            User u = new User(1, userE, false);
            fbIds.add(u.getFacebookId());
            if (fbIds.size() >= count)
                break;
    }           

        List<User> users = UserModule.getInstance().readUsersByFacebookIds(1, fbIds, 0, 0);

        return jsn.toJson(users);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return STR.getStackTrace(e);
    }
}
```

My second attempt was to scan a number of users and skip those where facebookId is null.

Attempt #2 - Also times out ...

```
public String testFbFriends(int count) {
    try {
        DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
        Query q = new Query("User");
        // q.setFilter(new FilterPredicate("facebookId", Query.FilterOperator.NOT_EQUAL, null));
        PreparedQuery pq = ds.prepare(q);
        List<String> fbIds = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Entity userE : pq.asIterable(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(count * 4).chunkSize(100))) {
            User u = new User(1, userE, false);
            if (u.getFacebookId() != null) {
                fbIds.add(u.getFacebookId());
                if (fbIds.size() >= count)
                    break;
            }
    }           

        List<User> users = UserModule.getInstance().readUsersByFacebookIds(1, fbIds, 0, 0);

        return jsn.toJson(users);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return STR.getStackTrace(e);
    }
}
```

**So does anyone out there know how to scan some records from a HUGE table?**

Big thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using cursors?

```
 ...
Query q = new Query("User");

if (cursorString != null) {
    Cursor cursor = Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursorString);
        Map<String, Object> extensionMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        extensionMap.put(JDOCursorHelper.CURSOR_EXTENSION, cursor);
        q.setExtensions(extensionMap);
}
q.setRange(0, range);
...retrieve entities...
Cursor cursor = JDOCursorHelper.getCursor(results);
cursorString = cursor.toWebSafeString();
...
```

With cursors you can set the number of entities retrieved in each call, and avoid timeout.